# How do you serve CSS in a node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been messing around with node.js and I can't seem to serve my CSS properly. Before, I had it embedded in my HTML in the header under a  tag, but now I'm trying to learn how to serve it as a separate file.

So far, this is what I did. I tried to just write it in before adding loading the HTML under the server:

```
//This is all my main module

var http = require('http');
var router = require('./router.js');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

response.writeHead(200,{"Content-type" : "text/css"});
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./views/styles.css', {encoding: "utf8"}, function(err, data) {
 if (!err) {
   response.write(data);
} else {
  console.log(err);
}
});

  router.home(request, response);
  router.user(request, response);

});

server.listen(3000);
```

The home function that I called in the router module looks like this. It works perfectly fine too:

```
function home(request, response) {
  //if url == "/" && GET

if (request.url === "/"){
if(request.method.toLowerCase() === "get") {
  response.writeHead(200, commonHeaders);
  renderer.view("header", {}, response);
  renderer.view("search", {}, response);
  renderer.view("footer", {}, response);
  response.end();

} else {
    //if url == "/" && POST
//redirect to /:username

  request.on("data", function(postBody) {
    var query = querystring.parse(postBody.toString());
    response.writeHead(303, {"Location":"/" + query.username});
    response.end();
  });
  }
 }
}
```

All of my HTML loads perfectly fine. If I use my dev tools in chrome, it shows that I've created a separate folder with a styles.css file in it, but it's empty. How come it's creating my file, but my CSS isn't being written in there?

Am I doing this all wrong? I have a stylesheet linked in the header of my HTML as well. How do you serve CSS in a node.js application? I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to serve the CSS through the node process, instead of directly (e.g. handled by nginx)? As it is a static asset, there is no need to burden the node process with it.

Comment: @m-a-r-c-e-l-I-n-o's answer below is correct for what you're doing. However, I would *strongly* suggest you bring in a web app framework such as Express (the most popular on the Node market) rather than trying to handle the http request/response cycle through the native modules.  Static file serving is probably best handled via NGINX or similar, but even if you don't have access to NGINX or for whatever reason want to go 'pure' node, using Express will save  you a ton of time and headaches.

Comment: @Paul valid point, and if you do take that route (Robert) and it's still not working as expected, you might still need access to the server to make sure the files are being served with the correct mime type, otherwise you'll see an empty `styles.css` file in chrome dev tools again.

Comment: I'm mostly just trying to learn how it works. It does seem like a bad idea, and it's been a headache so far. It's not for a project or anything -- I'm just trying to learn how one could serve CSS. I plan on getting Express and learning how handle requests and responses through that though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> All of my HTML loads perfectly fine. If I use my dev tools in chrome,
>   it shows that I've created a separate folder with a styles.css file in
>   it, but it's empty. How come it's creating my file, but my CSS isn't
>   being written in there?

It's likely because `fs.readFileSync` is synchronous and yet a callback is being erroneously provided for it. Try this instead:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/css'});
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync('./views/styles.css', {encoding: 'utf8'});
response.write(fileContents);
response.end();
```

> Am I doing this all wrong? I have a stylesheet linked in the header of
>   my HTML as well. How do you serve CSS in a node.js application?

Wrong is a strong word, but yeah, it's not the best idea to manually serve static files this way, it likely will not scale. What you ought to do is configure your web server to serve all static files, and only deal with dynamic content in Node.js. I won't touch on specifics, but ask another question here on Stack Overflow specifying the server that you are running and how you could properly configure it with Node.js. Alternatively, you could look up some tutorials on how to run Node.js with the NGINX server — that should get you on a more sustainable path.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried that, but now when I'm use it, it just replaces my page with plain text of my CSS. I guess this is much harder than I thought. I'm learning node, and was just trying to learn how to do this just to see the process. It's not for a real project or anything. I will for sure though check out NGINX, but this is still frustrating me on why this doesn't work, when in my head, it seems like it should.

Comment: Not a problem :)
Why don't you try creating a route for your css (i.e. `router.css(request, response)` and, inside of it, put the code I'm suggesting in my post and wrap it in an if statement targeting only the css file `if (request.url === "/styles.css")`. I think that the part that you're failing to realize is that the css does not get sent along with your pages. Your html pages go on their own, and once they arrive on the client, the client will request that file from the server (assuming they have an html css tag — i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`), does that make sense?

Comment: It worked! I see what you're saying. I removed my previous attempt to "serve" the css, and then saw that under my dev tools, that the styles.css still existed because the link tag in my HTML was still referencing that file, even though it didn't exist. So I set it up so that the css was requested first, and then my HTML could be styled because it found the stylesheet being referenced in the link. Your last bit really cleared a lot up for me. I took your suggestion, and it worked flawlessly. I understand how this works now. Thank you so much, you've been of tremendous help.

Comment: Not a problem, Robert! I'm happy to hear that you got it sorted out. Please consider marking this answer as "correct" (by clicking on the grey check mark at the top left of this post), if you felt that it properly addressed your question. Good luck :)

Comment: Also, one more thing to add. In my HTML css tag, my href used to be _href='./views/styles.css'_, but as you said, the CSS doesn't get sent along with the pages. So instead I had to make the HTML css tag reference the client's files, and not the servers files, so by your suggestion, I made it _href='styles.css'_. Again, thank you so much for your help. I've been struggling with this for a while hah.

Comment: Precisely, haha. No problem!